# 2nd display repeatedly loses connection when adb bridge is runnning

Tags: adb, external-display

I am currently working on a project which includes smartphone instrumentation via FRIDA, which requires me to attach to the device via adb. Somehow, once the adb bridge is online my 2nd display keeps losing the connection, which results in the screen to turn of for 2-3 seconds every 10-15 seconds which is quite annoying. I am working on a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and have two external displays attached to it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems a strange issue since I didn't realize ADB may affect other devices. Also, just want to let you know that we also have a sister site [ubuntu.se] for a community with Ubuntu experts since while this question looks on-topic on this site, I'm afraid the issue may be related more to Ubuntu (e.g. drivers conflict?), not Android.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Andrew. I'll post the question there.